# Meteor: how best to update records on server or client

Tags: meteor

I have a list of links with a `data-trackingId` which is basically just the value of `Random.id()`.  The way I have this currently set up is that when a link is clicked the tracking id is sent to the server and the relevant collection is updated.

The problem is that the client doesn't automatically update, it requires a page refresh to update the list of links.

I need to set an `active` flag and increment the `clickcount`.  I could achieve this by using the `_id` of the collection I want to update as the trackingId (as untrusted code can only update by `_id`).

However I don't want the client to be able to run the query which would set the `active` flag or increment the `clickcount` thereby bypassing the whole point of clicking the links.

What would be the best way to approach this?  The only things I can think of is perhaps setting some sort of permission within the publish/subscribe methods (which I'm not too familiar with) or use callbacks when calling `Meteor.call('serverMethod', trackingId)` so that I can pull the list of links back again.  I would think that its probably best to use the client and set permissions but I'm not sure exactly what I would need to do.

All suggestions welcome :)

Comment: In my memory you can create your own "reactive variables".. but I would suggest using Meteor.call. it saved me a lot of time :D

Comment: Yeah I'm using Meteor.call at the moment and it works, just doesn't react.  I'll have a think about it, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using callback functions.  If anyone has any better suggestions I'm open to alternatives.

In client code:

```
Meteor.call('updateTracking', Session.get('trackingId'), function(err, data){
                                                       if(err){
                                                          console.log(err)
                                                       }
                                                       Session.set('links', data);
                                                     });
```

in server.js

```
 updateTracking: function(trackingId){
     console.log('trackingId: ' + trackingId)
    Tracking.update({  trackingId: trackingId},
                              {$set: {active: 0},
                               $inc: {clickcount: 1}
                           });
  return Meteor.call('getLinks');
 },
```